# python to filter dictionary and get relevant data specific text

Tags: python

I'm currently having this being **scraped** from an exchange via API

```
prices = [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.02167400'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00595900'}, {'symbol': 'BNBBTC', 'price': '0.00201020'}, {'symbol': 'NEOBTC', 'price': '0.00103300'}, {'symbol': 'QTUMETH', 'price': '0.00860500'}]
```

i would like to get symbols that only contain BTC.

I tried this method

```
# initializing search key string 
search_key = 'BTC'
  
# printing original dictionary 
print("The original dictionary is : " + str(prices)) 
  
# Using items() + list comprehension 
# Substring Key match in dictionary 
res = [val for key, val in prices.items() if search_key in key]
```

but i realize it doesn't return anything because now the prices are wrapped in such a way that its a few wrapper in one big bracket. How should i proceed with this so i can get a search_key of BTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
res = [val for val in prices if search_key in val['symbol']] 

# [{'symbol': 'ETHBTC', 'price': '0.02167400'}, {'symbol': 'LTCBTC', 'price': '0.00595900'}, {'symbol': 'BNBBTC', 'price': '0.00201020'}, {'symbol': 'NEOBTC', 'price': '0.00103300'}]
```

Be careful not mixing dictionary- and list-comprehensions.

Comment: thanks! it worked just as expected! I'm still very much confused on dictionary and listing